# Aggregate nested data using Underscore Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rest, underscore.js

I have the following raw data, and I would like to aggregate it to return an object with total for each location, and perhaps a grand total too.

**Location A would be 760**

122 (costPrice) * 4 (quantity) = 488 (ALCATEL 5054)

136 * 2 = 272 (DESIRE 530)

**Location B would be 300**

104 * 2 = 208 (ALCATEL 6060)

92 * 1 = 92 (ALCATEL 7972)

Grand total: 1060

How can I perform the following data transformation using underscore js?

I started this plunker, but don't think I am going in the right direction...
http://plnkr.co/edit/ThvyQB3tm5KFuE6oLM1n?p=preview

Raw Data:

```
[{
    "location": {
        "id": 82008938,
        "name": "LOCATION A",
        "phone": "",
        "address": ""
    },
    "model": {
        "id": 610214643353,
        "name": "ALCATEL 5054",
        "costPrice": 122,
        "wholesalePrice": 127
    },
    "order": "5698",
    "sim": [358848659378096]
}, {
    "location": {
        "id": 82009723,
        "name": "LOCATION B",
        "phone": "",
        "address": ""
    },
    "model": {
        "id": 610214648136,
        "name": "ALCATEL 6060",
        "costPrice": 104,
        "wholesalePrice": 120
    },
    "order": "5698",
    "sim": [358899043576662]
}, {
    "location": {
        "id": 82008938,
        "name": "LOCATION A",
        "phone": "",
        "address": ""
    },
    "model": {
        "id": 610214643353,
        "name": "ALCATEL 5054",
        "costPrice": 122,
        "wholesalePrice": 127
    },
    "order": "5698",
    "sim": [358885796982333]
}, {
    "location": {
        "id": 82009723,
        "name": "LOCATION B",
        "phone": "",
        "address": ""
    },
    "model": {
        "id": 610214648136,
        "name": "ALCATEL 6060",
        "costPrice": 104,
        "wholesalePrice": 120
    },
    "order": "5698",
    "sim": [358817108459730]
}, {
    "location": {
        "id": 82008938,
        "name": "LOCATION A",
        "phone": "",
        "address": ""
    },
    "model": {
        "id": 610214643353,
        "name": "ALCATEL 5054",
        "costPrice": 122,
        "wholesalePrice": 127
    },
    "order": "5698",
    "sim": [358879619289409]
}, {
    "location": {
        "id": 82008938,
        "name": "LOCATION A",
        "phone": "",
        "address": ""
    },
    "model": {
        "id": 610214643353,
        "name": "ALCATEL 5054",
        "costPrice": 122,
        "wholesalePrice": 127
    },
    "order": "5698",
    "sim": [358842400527891]
}, {
    "location": {
        "id": 82009723,
        "name": "LOCATION B",
        "phone": "",
        "address": ""
    },
    "model": {
        "id": 610214647597,
        "name": "ALCATEL 7972",
        "costPrice": 92,
        "wholesalePrice": 95
    },
    "order": "5709",
    "sim": [358842726462666]
}, {
    "location": {
        "id": 82008938,
        "name": "LOCATION A",
        "phone": "",
        "address": ""
    },
    "model": {
        "id": 610214646606,
        "name": "DESIRE 530",
        "costPrice": 136,
        "wholesalePrice": 149
    },
    "order": "5710",
    "sim": [358840719743714, 358848337490208]
}]
```

Possible Desire Result (could be different format, with same data and total):

```
[{
    "location": "LOCATION A",
    "total": 760
}, {
    "location": "LOCATION B",
    "total": 300
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = [ /* raw data */ ];

var results = _.reduce(data, function(results, item){
  results[item.location.name] = (results[item.location.name]|0) + item.model.costPrice;
  return results;
}, {});
```

Which sets `results` to:

```
{ 
  "LOCATION A": 624, 
  "LOCATION B": 300
}
```

(It's 624 instead of 760 because there's only one instance of "DESIRE 530" in the sample data provided in your question.)

There's also `_.each()` which can be used to do the same thing in your case:

```
var results = {};
_.each(data, function(item){
  results[item.location.name] = (results[item.location.name]|0) + item.model.costPrice;
});
```

Reference:

- [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pd7oaoc/)
- [`_.reduce(list, iteratee, [memo], [context])`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce)
- [`_.each(list, iteratee, [context])`](http://underscorejs.org/#each)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Although there is only one instance of "DESIRE 530", the price is calculated by the length of the sim (2 in this case) so it would be 136 * 2 = 272. Sorry if I didn't make this clear in the question. But I was able to multiply costPrice by item.sim.length to get what I needed. Thank you!